# How twitter requests data for loading new tweets?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I need to point out that I am not talking about the API that they provide but rather what they use to download the content when you are just scrolling the page.

I have managed to get the request which I believe is driving the whole thing, but I don't quite grasp how it works.

Here it is URL encoded:

```
https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/u7I0lIRjA96yhblCP2akgA/UserTweetsAndReplies?variables=%7B%22userId%22%3A%221689053936%22%2C%22count%22%3A40%2C%22cursor%22%3A%22HBaKgLOFsoP%2BpykAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22includePromotedContent%22%3Atrue%2C%22withCommunity%22%3Atrue%2C%22withSuperFollowsUserFields%22%3Atrue%2C%22withDownvotePerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsMetadata%22%3Afalse%2C%22withReactionsPerspective%22%3Afalse%2C%22withSuperFollowsTweetFields%22%3Atrue%2C%22withVoice%22%3Atrue%2C%22withV2Timeline%22%3Afalse%2C%22__fs_dont_mention_me_view_api_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22__fs_interactive_text_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22__fs_responsive_web_uc_gql_enabled%22%3Afalse%7D
```

And here are the decoded variables:

```
{
  "userId": "1689053936",
  "count": 40,
  "cursor": "HBaKgLOFsoP+pykAAA==",
  "includePromotedContent": true,
  "withCommunity": true,
  "withSuperFollowsUserFields": true,
  "withDownvotePerspective": false,
  "withReactionsMetadata": false,
  "withReactionsPerspective": false,
  "withSuperFollowsTweetFields": true,
  "withVoice": true,
  "withV2Timeline": false,
  "__fs_dont_mention_me_view_api_enabled": false,
  "__fs_interactive_text_enabled": false,
  "__fs_responsive_web_uc_gql_enabled": false
}
```

So, what I don't understand here is `u7I0lIRjA96yhblCP2akgA` in the link and `cursor` In the variables. Where does this come from? How do they pass to the API which tweets in particular need to be loaded? How would one construct this request by themselves?

Comment: If you are scraping twitter data and want to send another page request to get posts then maybe you can't do that just because of the cursor field as it is the unique generated key. Which you cannot have while scraping.

Comment: @GhazniAli It is possible for me to open a browser for a little while to get this key if that is the case, however, I believe that it should be generated within a page, so one should be able to reproduce it with no issues. (Just a guess tho)

Comment: This is not a public Twitter API endpoint, so there is no reason for you to use it. Use the official API.